# Java 2D Game - Jumping only if the player is on the ground

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm making a 2D platformer and just added gravity & jumping.

It works like it should, however, if the space bar is still held down after the player finishes a jump, the player just keeps jumping while in mid-air.

I know I need to check for whether or not the player is actually on the ground, but when I do it always returns as 'false', as described in my jumping method:

```
// Controls both falling and the jumping action.
// The MapObject list is a collection of every object the player can
// collide with on that map. Currently it only contains a single 'ground' object.

    public void fall(ArrayList<MapObject> objects)
{
    int distance = 0;

    if (jumpTicks > 0)
    {
        float jumpHeight = jumpSpeed * (jumpTicks / maxJumpTicks);
        System.out.println(jumpTicks + "/" + maxJumpTicks + " = " + jumpHeight);
        y -= jumpHeight;
        jumpTicks--;
    }
    else
    {
        for (MapObject obj : objects)
        {
            if (this.y + this.height >= obj.y)
            {
                // This cancels falling if the player's feet are on top
                // of the ground, but for some reason setting an 'isOnGround'
                // boolean to 'true' here and checking for it in the 'jump()'
                // method does not work, it's always 'false'.
                return;
            }
            distance = obj.y - (this.y + this.height);
        }
        if (distance > fallSpeed)
        {
            y += fallSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            y += distance;
        }

    }
}

// This doesn't make the player jump, it just adds jump time to the player
// if it's not already jumping.

public void jump()
{
    if (jumpTicks > 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    this.jumpTicks = maxJumpTicks;
    this.jumpSpeed = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you change his speed, check his `y` value for the floor

```
function jump() {
    if (jumpTicks > 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.y === floorY) {
        this.jumpTicks = maxJumpTicks;
        this.jumpSpeed = 10;
    }
}
```